# Javascript console.log not reading array undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having issues with reading some data where I'm getting undefined:

```
obj = {
    "people": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "description": "some desc",
            "names": [
                {
                    "name": "Mark"
                }]
        }]

}

console.log(obj.people[0].names.name);
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: `console.log(obj.people[0].names[0].name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`names` is an array, make it

```
console.log(obj.people[0].names[0].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

`names` is also an array.

Try this,

```
console.log(obj.people[0].names[0].name);
```